# Multilanguage View path translation

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I'm building a multilanguage site and I have a View of taxonomy terms with the following configuration

[image: view configuration]

when I hover the menu Wines I can see the /en/products link, that's perfect
when I switch to my second language if I hover the menu it shows /it/products

I managed to translate the menu entry "Wines" so now it shows the Italian word "Vini" while browsing the /it/ site, but not the Path, I'd like it to be /it/prodotti

Using URL Aliases doesn't work, I can add the alias but if I type /it/prodotti it gives page not found.

I don't have this problem with Pages, only with Views, is there a solution?
The rest of the website works perfectly with the 2 enabled languages: language switch, translations, menus, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Translated views will need language-specific path aliases.

You'll add a path alias as normal at `/admin/config/search/path/add`

But make sure to set the path as the desired language with the language dropdown select. Do not add the language prefix, Drupal will handle that based on the language selection from the dropdown.

Example image:

[image: View of alias language select for English or spanish example]

Comment: thanks! with the Alias I can access the view from the IT path /it/prodotti, but the menu still shows the /it/products if I hover it.
both paths point to the correct view, I could live with that, but it looks like a workaround rather than the proper way

Comment: The translation of the menu link title would be handled under the translation of the view `/admin/structure/views/view/MYVIEW/translate/LANGCODE/edit` in "Page display options". Make sure to clear cache

Comment: the menu link title is translated correctly inside the section you mentioned and the word is switched correctly between languages when the user change the site's language. it's the word within the actual link that's not translated. I would like to use /it/prodotti for the Italian version of the site and /en/products for the English version. currently it's /en/products for EN and /it/products for IT

Comment: If the menu link is provided by the view, and the views link is translated, and you've created a language-specific path alias, the link browser tooltip should show correctly when hovering over the link. Have you tried an incognito browser just to help eliminate cache?

Comment: technically the view's actual link is not translated, at least not the way other things like menu entries or titles are translated. I have a path alias for a specific language, I think the problem could be here. I can't find a page where I have the usual left textbox for one language - right textbox for the translation, the way it works with any kind of text translation